# Stop jackson-scala-module serializing all fields by default

Tags: json, scala, jackson, jackson-modules, jackson-module-scala

Using [`DefaultObjectMapper`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/blob/fd3055b932e468ce784b4ffb090ccd899f221d57/src/main/scala/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/DefaultScalaModule.scala) from [`jackson-scala-module`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala), in the following examples, `field` *is* serialised in the Scala version, but not in the Java version. Setting [`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_FIELDS`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Mapper-Features) has no effect.

I wish for no fields to be serialised unless a field is annotated with `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude`.

**Scala**

```
class ScalaClass {
  val field = "someField"
}
```

**Java**

```
public class JavaClass {
  public String field = "someField";
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead, disable `MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS` and use `@JsonGetter` on a field.

This works for me:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonGetter
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{MapperFeature, ObjectMapper, SerializationFeature}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

mapper.disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS)
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

class ScalaClass {
  val field = "someField"
  @JsonGetter val includedField = "fieldValue"
}

mapper.writer().writeValueAsString(new ScalaClass) // => res: String = {"includedField":"fieldValue"}
```

The Java analogy to your Scala class is more likely to be:

```
public class JavaClass {
    public String getField() { return "someField"; }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Used `@JsonGetter` to include the field in serialization.

Comment: This successfully prevents the fields being serialised which is interesting since the fields are not annotated with `@BeanProperty`, so no JavaBeans getter/setter methods are generated.

However, annotating fields with `@JsonInclude` does not override the setting, so the fields cannot be included again on a case-by-case basis.

This is therefore only a partial answer.

Comment: @oloftus ah! I forgot about that part :) let me see what can be done in that regard..

Comment: @oloftus the only way I found is to use `@JsonGetter` on a field